# Внешние ключи в MySQL

Tags: mysql

У меня есть БД, пытаюсь перенести ее на хостинг на MySQL. Создал, допустим, две таблицы:

- `Table1 (ID1, Name1)`
- `Table2 (ID2,ID1, Name2, Quantity)`

ID1 (в табл.1) и ID2 - это primary, а как сделать так, чтобы ID2 ссылался на ID1? Что-то типа такого не работает:

```
ALTER TABLE Table2  FOREIGN KEY  ID2 REFERENCES Table1 (ID1)
```

Comment: Почему ID2, а не ID1? И пропущено ADD: `ALTER TABLE Table2  ADD FOREIGN KEY  ID1 REFERENCES Table1 (ID1)`

Comment: ошибки это не меняет...

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'REFERENCES Table1(ID1)' at line 1

Comment: sorry, конечно же, список колонок надо заключать в скобки.
`ALTER TABLE Table2  ADD FOREIGN KEY  (ID1) REFERENCES Table1 (ID1);`

Comment: Покажите результат:
 
    SHOW CREATE TABLE Table1;
     SHOW CREATE TABLE Table2;

Answer (score 1):

вынесено из комментариев.

---

пропущено `ADD`:

```
ALTER TABLE Table2 ADD FOREIGN KEY (ID1) REFERENCES Table1 (ID1);
```